# How to retrieve dynamic tab data in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, tabs

I am trying to display data from database in a dynamic Tabs, So I have two tables... Queues and Station.

**Queues Table**

[image]

**Station Table**

[image]

Now I want to retrieve all stations in the **Nav Tabs** and all Queues with the target Schedule in the **Tab Content**

i have tried like the following.

```
<ul  class="nav nav-tabs">
@forelse ($stations as $station)
    <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-{{ $station->id }}"  >
        {!! $station->name !!}
    </a></li>
@empty

@endforelse
</ul>

<div style="margin-top: 15%"  class="tab-content">
    @foreach($queues as $station_id => $item)
        <div id="tab-{{ $station->id }}" class="tab-pane fade">
            @foreach($item as $queue)
                <p>{!! $queue->bus_number !!}</p>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Does anyone know another way of getting done this? Again, want to display all stations in the first **navtab** and **tab-content** I want to fetch all target station's queues. And thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this portion. `$station->id to $station_id`

```
<div style="margin-top: 15%"  class="tab-content">
    @foreach($queues as $station_id => $item)
        <div id="tab-{{ $station->id }}" class="tab-pane fade">
            @foreach($item as $queue)
                <p>{!! $queue->bus_number !!}</p>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stingy
I did the following. equals to 2 foreach
the tab get the number of heads

```
  @foreach ($category is $category)
```

the 2 to spill data

```
 @foreach ($category->products as $product)
```